# Handle any optional after segue

Tags: swift, core-data, option-type

I am still new in the language swift. I do not come from the following after a day of searching.
After a segue I send the following data as an Any? object.

```
Optional(<Hond: 0x604000297cf0> (entity: Hond; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://9C4A92D6-5E7D-4633-827E-0E2BB6F005CA/Hond/p2> ; data: {
    chipnummer = 0;
    dierenarts = "";
    geboortedatum = "2015-11-28 08:56:33 +0000";
    geslacht = 0;
    gewicht = 0;
    hondId = "30A102CB-E0A5-49F1-ABAA-6E73CA32AF43";
    kleur = "";
    naam = Ravi;
    orderID = 1;
    plaatsVanChip = "";
    schofthoogte = 0;
    telefoonnummerDierenarts = "";
    vachttype = ""; }))
```

Now I think that I must treat the data as an optional, but that does not work at all. Now my question is how can I display the values such as name and date?

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreData

    class hondDetialView: UIViewController {

        var hond:Any?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //print(hond as Any)

            if let eenWaarde = hond {
                print(eenWaarde)
            }
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
```

thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any` is the worst choice.

It's the most unspecified type in Swift. It tells the compiler *I-have-no-idea-what-it-is*. And the compiler doesn't know that there are properties like `naam` and `geboortedatum`.

You know that the type is `Hond`, so declare the property

```
var hond: Hond?
```

even `NSManagedObject` would be much better than `Any`. Then you can write

```
if let eenWaarde = hond {
    print(eenWaarde.naam)
}
```

---

If the segue sends always a `Hond` instance you can even declare the property as implicit unwrapped optional

```
var hond: Hond!
```

and omit the optional binding

```
print(hond.naam)
```